# Log deleted files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, logging

Cleanup script:

```
. $HOME/u0146121
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

I have deleted files that are 7 days or older, but now I would like to log what I deleted. Do I have to use piping? I am a beginner in shell scripting.

Comment: You might get better help for this question on http://superuser.com/ rather than on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested

```
log=$HOME/OldLogFiles/deleted.log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime +7 -delete -print > "$log"
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! Do you know how to change the new log file to maybe the current date and then clean up how it actually logs the file ? Is that asking too much?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The new deleted log does have the current date in it. What specifically is "unclean" about what it contains?

Comment: I would like it to produce a log file that displays the date as the name. One you open up the file its rather unreadable. For example, /home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file1.txt/home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file2.txt
I was just wondering if theres a way to display the information better.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why the newlines are missing. Try `-printf "%T+\t%p\n"` instead of `-print`. For more details: man find.

Comment: That makes it look a lot better. Can you tell me what-printf "%T+\t%p\n" does?